preventing Linux session unresponsiveness during heavy NFS write
Given this scenario:

on a 100gbp infiniband LAN, (same happens over the 1gbps LAN)
a RHEL-8.10 host controller server having a SCSI cable connection to an enterprise type data storage unit that provides a 100TB /data folder, having an XFS file system and an "ADAPT" raid protection choice over 50+ disks (versus RAID-5, 0/1, etc), and where this is the nfs_server as 192.168.1.1,
an NFS client (i.e. 192.168.1.2), also a RHEL-8.10 server, mounts 192.168.1.1:/data /data with proto=rdma and as NFS version 4.2
a scp from nfs client to nfs server writing a single ~100gb test.tar file achieves 1.0 GB/sec speeds,
typically a copy over NFS runs around 400MB/sec or better,

Problem is when a user does a basic copy of cp /home/ron/bigdata.tar  /data/run1/ where that data file is somewhere between 100-500gb in size, all nfs clients mounting the /data folder from the nfs server become unresponsive with regards to the GNOME desktop and even any putty ssh terminal connection - if you try to do various cd /data/run2/ or cd /data/anywhere on an nfs client and especially if you hit tab you use bash completion to traverse the folder structure, you session hangs.  Once that copy, which seems to be getting 100% resource usage of the nfs_server host controller to the 100tb storage array finishes, then things seemingly go back to normal and users get acceptable responsiveness on their existing sessions.  But during that write, their logging sessions become unresponsive and it is unacceptable.
Is there a way to correct this?  Is there a specific tuned profile to choose?  I would rather have the copy (write) process be lower priority and give priority to whatever processes are involved in making a pleasant and responsive user experience when logged in and simply traversing the folder paths under /data which is nfs mounted.
